# Rails: Modeling an optional relation in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to map a relation between two Rails models, where one side can be optionnal. Let's me be more precise...

I have two models: `Profile` that stores user profile information (name, age,...) and `User` model that stores user access to the application (email, password,...).

To give you more information, `User` model is handled by Devise gem for signup/signin.

Here is the scenario of my app:

1/ When a user register, a new row is created in `User` table and there is an equivalent in `Profile` table. This leads to the following script:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile
end
```

2/ A user can create it's profile without registering (kind of public profile with public information), so a row in `Profile` doesn't have necessarily a `User` row equivalent (here is the optional relation, the `0..1` relation in UML).

**Question:** What is the corresponding script to put in `class Profile < AR::Base` to map optionally with `User`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't assign it to a user?

Comment: I must assign it, because it will help me to get the `User` information when they exist.

Comment: It's optional by default. If it isn't assigned, then you'll get nil back, like @Doon was saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Profile << ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

All AR relations are optional (at least by default - I'm not sure if you can insist they exist). If you ask for `profile.user` where the relation isn't set, you'll just get `nil` back.

Comment: you can make them required by setting a not null constraint on the foreign key, and using validates_associated ..

Comment: So, `has_one` doens't mean that "there is strictly 1" but "that there is up to 1" (which means 0 or 1)?

Comment: @Hassinus - exactly so. In fact, I guess all it means is "when asked for the related object, look in its table for a single matching this_id"